# Making a list horizontally and vertically scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have a table, where each cell has a vertical list. However, some cells have text that is horizontally too wide, so I want it to be horizontally scrollable inside the list div.

I have tried something like this, but that gives me only the vertically scrollable list, but horizontally is my content not scrollable.

```
ol {
  height: 160px;

  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

td {
  height: 200px;
}


li {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 95%;
}
```

How do I make the content of my list (each list item) horizontally scrollable where needed?

Comment: Try to set table-layout: fixed; for your table and overflow-x:auto; for the td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A code sample would be great, but regardless, here's a sample that allows vertical and horizontal scrolling inside a table cell. (Did I understand your requirements correctly?)

```css
td {
max-width:100px;
max-height:100px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: auto;
display:block;
}

li {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td>
<ul>
  <li>Foobar testklst tesjktl tjekslt tjkeslt tekljst tjesklt</li>
  <li>Foobar ljfse selfjse lfjase asliejfasj as asefklj</li>
  <li>Foobar ljfse selfjse lfjase asliejfasj as asefklj</li>
  <li>Foobar ljfse selfjse lfjase asliejfasj as asefklj</li>
  <li>Foobar ljfse selfjse lfjase asliejfasj as asefklj</li>
  <li>Foobar ljfse selfjse lfjase asliejfasj as asefklj</li>
  <li>Foobar ljfse selfjse lfjase asliejfasj as asefklj</li>
</ul>
</td></tr></table>
```